# Interop: HmacSHA1 in Java and dotNet

Tags: c#, java, interop, cryptography, hmac

In an app we are calculating a SHA1Hmac in java using the following:

```
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(secret, "HmacSHA1");
Mac m = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
m.init(key);
byte[] hmac = m.doFinal(data);
```

And later, the hmac is verified in C# - on a SmartCard - using:

```
  HMACSHA1 hmacSha = new HMACSHA1(secret);
  hmacSha.Initialize();
  byte[] hmac = hmacSha.ComputeHash(data);
```

However, the result is not the same. Did I overlook something important?

The inputs seem to be the same. Here some sample inputs:

```
Data: 546573746461746131323341fa3c35
Key: 6d795472616e73616374696f6e536563726574

Result Java: 37dbde318b5e88acbd846775e38b08fe4d15dac6
Result C#:   dd626b0be6ae78b09352a0e39f4d0e30bb3f8eb9
```

I wouldn't mind to implement my own hmacsha1 on both platforms, but using what already exists....

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a typo, but shouldn't you pass "key" to m.init instead of "secret"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this Java code:

```
static byte[] doHMAC(byte[] data, byte[] secret)
{
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(secret, "HmacSHA1");
    Mac m = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    m.init(key);
    return m.doFinal(data);
}
```

then I get the `dd626b0be6ae78b09352a0e39f4d0e30bb3f8eb9` which is what you have from your C# implementation. Also, I have verified that value with regards to my own HMAC and SHA-1 implementation (in Java) and I also get that result.

It seems that your Java code is flawed, but not in the part you show (except your `m.init(secret)` which does not compile -- it has to be `m.init(key)`). As my code shows, the Java implementation of HMAC/SHA-1 is correct and you invoke it properly. My guess is that you are not inputting the right data or key.

(I am using Sun's JDK 1.6.0_16)

Comment: I indeed had a code problem in java, your post helped me to pinpoint it. thx a lot!